# Mecab outputs strange characters when automatically splitting large files

Tags: mecab

**How to prevent Mecab from inputting strange characters before and after EOS when input buffer file size exceeded without increasing input buffer size?**

When running mecab with files that exceed the input buffer size, it'd automatically split the output. This is usually fine, except before and after EOS, there's the below unrecognizable characters.

```
�   �   �   �   補助記号-一般
 �&#65533;\uFFFD (character code)
```

Is there any settings that prevents mecab from outputting these strange characters? I need the file splitting to ensure morphemes are grouped properly. Going through the entire file and manually getting rid of them isn't the best option, especially when I have 10's of thousands of lines in the mecab output (due to lots of files).

Installed mecab via Homebrew with Unidict

Comment: I'm not really sure what's going on that would cause that, but MeCab really isn't intended for long input like a whole book or something - it was designed to handle once *sentence* at a time. I would recommend splitting your input on newlines or something to get it mostly below the buffer size.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't sound like a terrible solution, but it isn't ideal. I have thousands of files to parse, it'll take forever if I were to parse a single line at a time.

Comment: Have you actually tried it? It should not be slower. And this isn't really a speed tradeoff, it's that MeCab is not supposed to work that way...

Comment: I decided just to remove the strange characters from the output, easier that way.

Comment: Frankly I’m surprised Mecab doesn’t crash or segfaults if it reads beyond the end of its internal buffer. Most people would try to avoid a buffer overrun, not patch the behavior upon encountering one, but maybe you’ll be ok.

Comment: It's a 1-time run script so it's all fine. When outputting the files into to_chunk.py from Jdepp, it does crash, but that's just because it can't decide the character encoding. Keeping the buffer overrun splits mecab files automatically and prevents Jdepp from messing up the output. It's a long chain of dependencies :)